# Is human genome editing more complicated than mice genome editing?

Tags: human-biology, genetics, molecular-genetics, human-genetics

A lot of genome editing trials are being done on mice and rats, but I often read that the step from mice- to human genome editing is complicated. What are precisely? I guess it has something to do with human's more advanced immune system, but I would like to have a better general understanding of this.